# How do I enable debugging of the ASIFormDataRequest class?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, debugging, asiformdatarequest

I am using ASIFormDataRequest in my iphone project to post data to twitter api and was trying to debug why my request was returning 401.

I found that the code makes reference to a few macros:

```
#define ASIHTTPREQUEST_DEBUG 1
#define DEBUG_FORM_DATA_REQUEST 1
#define DEBUG_REQUEST_STATUS 1
#define DEBUG_THROTTLING 1
#define DEBUG_PERSISTENT_CONNECTIONS 1
```

but even setting them up it does not seem to add any extra logging... How am I supposed to debug that class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried defining the debug flag in ASIHTTPRequestConfig.h?

see http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#debugging_options

Answer (score 3):

Use [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) proxy for proper control on what data is actually transmitted and what it received by your app.